# libtool-regexp: OR-concatenate options

Tags: regex, linux, libtool

I fail with quite a simple problem with a regular expression for libtool-option -export-symbols-regex:

My library has to export several functions that start with "foo_" and "bar_". But the command line option

```
-export-symbols-regex '(foo_|bar_)'
```

seems to be wrong, only the foo_-functions are exported.

So: how should this regular expression look like to export both?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe escape the pipe?  `\|` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `(foo_|bar_)` does not ensure the substrings `foo_` and `bar_` appear at the start of the function name.

You should include the `^` start of string anchor.

```
^(foo_|bar_)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

More informatin about the start of string anchor can be found at [regular-expressions.info/anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)